# Example parsing error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to parse an example of boost spirit (2.5.2) following the example. My code is the following

```
#include <boost\spirit\home\qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{

  // Parsing two numbers
  std::string input("1.0 2.0");
  std::pair<double, double> p;

  boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(
    input.begin(),
    input.end(),
    boost::spirit::qi::double_ >> boost::spirit::qi::double_ , // Parse grammar
    boost::spirit::qi::space,
    p
  );

  return 0;
}
```

It's almost equal to the example found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/attributes/compound_attributes.html), but when I compile it with Visual studio 2010 (32 bit, debug) I obtain the following error:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast': unable to convert from 'const double' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>'
```

(the error can be slighty different, I've translated it from italian)

What I'm doing wrong and how can I compile successfully the example?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an include:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
```

It defines the attribute assignment rules to make Fusion sequences (vector2<>) assignable to std::pair.

See the code live: **[liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/0827918e0c74345b515c887f63b75a7d)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    // Parsing two numbers
    std::string input("1.2 3.4");
    std::pair<double, double> p;

    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    qi::phrase_parse(
            input.begin(), 
            input.end(),
            qi::double_ >> qi::double_ , // Parse grammar
            qi::space, p);

    std::cout << "Lo:     " << p.first << "\n"
              << "Behold: " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem. So I must to search an include like this for every structure that I want to parse, right?

Comment: It is usually mentioned in the documentation. However, the tests contain links to the full source files in case you are stuck.